# We can do better: FALSE

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, stack

The interpreter executable for [FALSE](http://esolangs.org/wiki/False) is 1020 bytes large. I think we can do better than THIS:

```
��Û������������������ˆ��È���ˆB0�ˇ*,x�r�pH@NÆ˝T,�g�Œ$F(FIÏa®.GÏu0C˙íp%NÆ˝ÿJÄg�™,@"$<��ÌNÆˇ‚JÄg�í*�"�$&<��a®NÆˇ÷,�"NÆˇ‹F�k�r‹Ç*BA˙¸C˙Ra�ºª∆j��Úp�@�0j�^@�[f(¸A˙�8¸+(¸`�ˇ¯&Ã`‘@�]f8¸Nu c êàTÄ1@ˇ˛`º@�aj�T@�!kÆ@�{fª∆j��ö�}fÙ`ö@�"fB(¸A˙�(¸`��� Lª∆j
�"g›`ÚRçB ���gB êàTÄ1@ˇ˛(¸"NÆ8¸¸L`�ˇT@�'fp�8¸+<(¿`�ˇ@@�`f
 $Uå8¿`�ˇ0A˙�ˆ∞(�fVàr�8ÿQ…ˇ¸`�ˇ2g��p–¡`‡A˙TC˙^a��∫ ��gB\ êáÄ��� ‰à(¸��Ú G!@�!@�A˙¬"$<��ÓNÆˇ‚(�g��$"�$&ñáNÆˇ–"NÆˇ‹"N,x�NÆ˛bap�NuaÓ`"JNÆ˝Np
Nu@�:j�˛ûr�¬¸�
@�0“Ä�0k�:jp�`‰8¸+<(¡`�˛d@�{j�˛®@�aÂH8¸AÏ8¿8¸+`�˛H  êà‚àSÄ8ÿQ»ˇ¸Nu�+ —ï�- ëï�* ¡Ì�*Ä�/ "É¿H¡*Å�.    `%ld�A˙ˇ˙"$
NÆ¸FXç�! ]Nê�: ] ù�; ]+�= ∞ïW¿HÄH¿*Ä�? ] gNê�$�+�%�Xç�\ *≠�+@��@ -�+m��+U�*Ä�_�Dï�& ¡ï�| Åï�~�Fï�> ∞ï[¿HÄH¿*Ä�#L›�HÁ�¿ o�NêJùg WNê`Pè�,"$NÆ˛»�^"NÆ˛Œ+��¯ Âà+5���ﬂ"NÆ˛ò"NÆ˛òa.out���Û���������������������È����KÔ˜�IÔ¯�(à,x�C˙�p%NÆ˝ÿJÄfNu,@NÆˇƒ,�NÆˇ *�`dos.library�"N,x�NÆ˛bp�Nu����Ú
```

## Challenge

Write a FALSE interpreter in any language (doesn't have to be an executable!). As usual, shortest bytes wins. Make sure to try to get it under 1020 though :)

## Language Specs

**Literals**

- `123` put integer onto the stack
- `'c` put character code onto the stack

**Stack**

- `$` DUP
- `%` DROP
- `\` SWAP
- `@` ROT
- `ø` PICK (dup the nth stack item)

**Arithmetic**

- `+` ADD
- `-` SUBTRACT
- `*` MULTIPLY
- `/` DIVIDE
- `_` negate (negative numbers are entered `123_`)
- `&` bitwise AND
- `|` bitwise OR
- `~` bitwise NOT

**Comparison** (false is zero, true is all bits set (-1 or ~0) so that bitwise operators may be used)

- `>` greater than
- `=` equals

**Lambdas and flow control** (tests are for non-zero)

- `[...]` define and put a lambda onto the stack
- `!` execute lambda
- `?` conditional execute: `condition[true]?`.

  - An if-else can be expressed as: `condition$[\true\]?~[false]?`
- `#` while loop: `[condition][body]#`

**Names**

- `a-z` put a reference to one of the 26 available variables onto the stack
- `:` store into a variable
- `;` fetch from a variable

**Input and Output**

- `^` read a character (-1 for end-of-input)
- `,` write a character
- `"string"` write a string (may contain embedded newlines)
- `.` write top of stack as a decimal integer
- `ß` flush buffered input/output

**Other**

- `{...}` comment
- whitespace is ignored, may be needed to separate consecutive integers

## Examples

Copy file:

```
{ copy.f: copy file. usage: copy < infile > outfile  }

ß[^$1_=~][,]#
```

Factorial:

```
{ factorial program in false! }

[$1=~[$1-f;!*]?]f:          { fac() in false }

"calculate the factorial of [1..8]: "
ß^ß'0-$$0>~\8>|$
"result: "
~[\f;!.]?
["illegal input!"]?"
"
```

Primes to 100:

```
{ writes all prime numbers between 0 and 100 }

99 9[1-$][\$@$@$@$@\/*=[1-$$[%\1-$@]?0=[\$.' ,\]?]?]#
```

Comment: I think the code you posted might not be displaying correctly. It probably contains unprintable characters. Can you provide a link to where you got the code?

Comment: Sure! http://strlen.com/files/lang/false/False12b.zip

Comment: Please include the language specification of FALSE in your challenge to make the post self-contained.

Comment: It might be a good idea to specify a controlled subset of FALSE. The inline machinecode facility of the language would make this considerably harder to implement portably, and the IO primitives might also limit participation by users of some languages.

Comment: What would you suggest removing?

Comment: @RK. The ` should be removed, as the inline machine code facility of the language would make this considerably harder to implement portably.(thanks @JohnE) The I/O can stay, imo.

Comment: Can you give some example programs with explanations?

Comment: I took some from the FALSE page on strlen.

Comment: @ConfusedMr_C I have no idea how your comment didn't show up in my notifications, but OK!

Comment: You say that a letter pushes a reference. What happens when you try to use an operator on a reference? E.g. `3 a +` Or can we be guaranteed that variables always occur adjacent to a `:` or `;`?

Comment: Also, can we be guaranteed to have a valid FALSE program as input?

Comment: I want to do this is [betaload](https://github.com/ScratchMan544/betaload-lang), but it's too complex. Things like `'` would need to recognize every character. That's too bad, because FALSE is really very similar to Underload.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I think math with references would be undefined behavior. Should we just edit the question and guarantee a valid input program so that the question can be on-topic?

Comment: @mbomb007 idk, there are still more problems. E.g. how does the flush command work?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Python has `sys.stdout.flush()`.